# Совместимость сайта c IE 6 и выше

Tags: веб-программирование, html, internet-explorer

Был создан веб-сайт, и тестировался только на IE 8 версии, и очень хорошо работал, но после запуска сайта на IE 6, сайт в некоторых местах разбился на несколько частей. Что сделать, чтобы сайт нормально работал на всех версия браузеров?

**Дополнение.**

А если использовать хаки:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]> (<!--[if lte IE 5.5]>
)
<![endif]-->
```

- gt – больше, чем
- lt – меньше, чем
- gte – больше или равно
- lte – меньше или равно
- ! – все, исключая указанное (символ "!" должен быть написан непосредственно перед условием).

Тогда как их правильно написать и использовать?

Comment: Выложите сюда код CSS и HTML.

Comment: В коде всё в порядке, может быть есть код для правильного отображения сайта на старых версиях браузеров.

Comment: Не думаю, что существуют css-стили или javascript-библиотеки, которые автоматически, без ручной работы, помогут сделать сайт совместимым во всех версиях IE. Скорее всего, придется самостоятельно править верстку или скрипты.

Comment: Могу написать скрипт, который будет определять версию браузера, но верстку все равно придется исправлять.

Answer (score 1):

У меня так для IE

```
    <!--[if IE 6]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/ie6/ie6.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/ie6/ie7.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/ie6/ie8.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

Т.е. в зависимости от браузера, будет подключаться дополнительный css. Вот в нём и нужно переопределить все "глючные" стили, сделать хаки, грубо говоря.

Comment: Этот код нужно вставить между тегами head?

Comment: Да.

Comment: Только это не хаки, а законный способ разделить стили.

Answer (score 0):

В head, после всех обычных стилей, поместить подобные строки надо:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        /* <![CDATA[ */ @import url(css/ie7.css); /* ]]> */
    </style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        /* <![CDATA[ */ @import url(css/ie.css); /* ]]> */
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Ну, в соответствующие файлы поместить особые правила для IE6 - обычно много разных переопределений, и для IE7 - поменьше. Для более старших всё неплохо. =)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). И еще - не верстайте под ие6 =) Его уже даже майкрософт за браузер не считает.

Comment: Угу, IE6 - нехорошая штука.

Comment: Я сайт верстал под IE8, просто после проверки его на IE6 возникли проблемы.